# Is SQL injection still possible after filtering?

Tags: php, sql-injection

I am just reviewing a script I want to use for my website. The author filters all user entered data (`$_POST` and `$_GET`) with this function:

```
function XSSCheck($value) {
    return preg_replace(
        array('/&(?!amp;|quot;|nbsp;|gt;|lt;|laquo;|raquo;|copy;|reg;|#[0-9]{1,5};|#x[0-9A-F]{1,4};)/', '/#(?![0-9]{1,5};|x[0-9A-F]{1,4};)/',       '|<|',  '|>|',  '|"|',      "|'|"   ),
        array('&amp;', '&#35;', '&lt;', '&gt;', '&#34;', '&#39;'),
        stripslashes($value)
    );
}
```

If I filter a string with that, would it possible to inject into this SQL query for example?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = '{$_REQUEST['id']}'
```

I tried it already but did not find out any way to do so.

Comment: Did you run the function against possible inputs to see what it does? Just by eyeballing the code I can see that it doesn't filter asterisks and curly braces. Also, the function name indicates it is filtering for [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and not for SQLi. See the [SQLi Cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for preventing that.

Comment: @NeilSmithline: I do not know why it is named `XSSCheck`. It also filters for SQL. The question is, provides this function an injection point which `mysql_real_escape_string` does not?

Comment: It is named `XSSCheck` because it is for preventing XSS attacks (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). XSS is an attack on the browser, not the database. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` for preventing SQL injection, use `XSSCheck` for preventing XSS.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` can be bypassed, and wouldn't be effective when the injection is numerical. Bind variables should be used instead with whitelisting.

Comment: [Same question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32670596/53114)

Answer (score 6):

Blacklists are a bad idea for protecting against vulnerabilities like XSS and SQLi. The reason is that there are so many encoding techniques, browser behaviors, database server inconsistencies, and web server bugs to account for that you'll never be able to build a blacklist of sufficient capability.

For this function, it will not be sufficient for XSS or SQL injection. For example, what about SQL injections outside of string literals? For both classes of vulnerabilities, there are recognized appropriate fixes.

### XSS

- Whitelist where appropriate: A number is a number, a string consists of A-Za-z0-9, etc.
- Where whitelisting can't be done, such as free-form search strings or comments, output encode.

### SQL injection

- Whitelist where appropriate: A number is a number, a string consists of A-Za-z0-9, the user can only select from tables you specify, etc.
- Use parameterized queries: PHP supports this. Even better, use an ORM so it takes care of it for you.

Comment: What is a purely numerical SQL injection?

Comment: Sure. I admit that was poorly worded. What I'm saying here is not breaking strings. `mysql_real_escape_string` is meant for strings. It escapes `'`, `"`, and a few other characters, but it'll not help with math `10-1` or hex-encoded injections (http://securitystreetknowledge.com/?p=193)

Answer (score 1):

You can not use that function to prevent SQL injections as @NeilSmithline commented you. The author of that function was right in calling it `XSSCheck()` because it is what you can use it for.

I feel you are just confused. [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) is a **server-side** vulnerability wheras  [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A3) is a **client-side** vulnerability. The techniques used to prevent these two attacks are also different. I suggest you to put this big difference in mind and read further about these two notions.

P.S.

Note that the function is missing few special characters such as backslashes.